# how do you convert a non Oracle Managed files into an Oracle Managed file

Tags: oracle

how do you convert a non Oracle Managed files into an Oracle Managed file

Answer (score 3):

The following parameters enable the Oracle to use OMF(Oracle Managed File).

`DB_CREATE_FILE_DEST`- For Datafiles

`DB_CREATE_ONLINE_LOG_DEST_n`- For redo log files.

`DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST`- For controlfiles.

To convert non-OMF datafiles to OMF-

1) Set the `db_create_file_dest` parameter.

```
alter system set db_Create_file_dest='+DATA';
```

2) `select file#, name from v$datafile;`--to list all the datafiles and their file number.

3) `alter database move datafile 1;` --repeat this for all datafiles.

To convert non-OMF redo log files to OMF

1) set the `DB_CREATE_ONLINE_LOG_DEST_n`

2) Create new OMF redo log files.

```
 alter database add LOGFILE group 5 size 100M;
```

3) Drop the old redo log files.

Comment: The above answer may work with 12c however it does not work with our 11g. This link [Migrate non-OMF files to OMF files](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/Tablespaces/TBS_8.shtml) provides a very comprehensive method for migrating normal files to Oracle Managed files.

Comment: dose these steps are applied on oracle 10 ?